# Unable to connect to the MySQL server

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, xampp

In admin properties, the paths are correct but, this error always appears whenever I try to connect to MySQL server from NetBeans.

> Unable to connect to the MySQl server:
>   org.netbeans.api.db.explorer.DatabaseException:Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306 for user root"

[image]

Comment: are you able to connect through mysql gui?

Comment: I tried to connect it to my gui, but there is still an error. When i start the Mysqlserver at localhost:3306, it tells that "Cannot establish a connection to :Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306 for user root"

Comment: can you post the exact error you are getting when connecting through gui?

Comment: java.sql.SQLException. No suitable driver found for jdbc://mysql://localhost:3306/database2

Comment: Also, when i tried to make a new connection in Services>Databases>New Connection and inserting host as localhost, database as database2(name of my database) and port as 3306.. username as root without a password. When i clicked the test connection, it displays "Too Long"... This is the first step in connecting which is i have an error with.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `Download Connector/J` (This is the official JDBC driver for MySQL.)

Official Download Page: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/